# Views Output field as a link - Two tokens, use only one of them

Tags: 7, views

I have content type which has field_pdf.
I have made view to show content and there is a field which has set: Output field as a link.
In link path settings I have two tokens: [field_pdf][path]. Idea is to link field either straight to PDF (if there is PDF file in node) or to content node.

How to get view to use only [field_pdf] when this field_pdf has content and not use [path] at all?

Now I'm getting double url for example: *http://url.com/pdf-file.pdfhttp://url.com/pdf*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modules You Need:**

1. [Views](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.x-dev.tar.gz)
2. [Views PHP](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views_php-7.x-2.x-dev.tar.gz)

Assuming your content type is having these fields:

[image: fields]

## The VIEWS Code:

Simply go to `admin/structure/views/import` and then Import the below mentioned code:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'pdf';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'PDF';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'PDF';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: Content: PDF */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_pdf']['id'] = 'field_pdf';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_pdf']['table'] = 'field_data_field_pdf';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_pdf']['field'] = 'field_pdf';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_pdf']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_pdf']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_pdf']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_pdf']['alter']['path'] = '[field_pdf][path]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_pdf']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Global: PHP */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['id'] = 'php';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['field'] = 'php';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['use_php_setup'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['php_output'] = '<?php
if (isset($data->field_field_pdf[0][\'rendered\'][\'#markup\'])) {
    $pdf_url = $data->field_field_pdf[0][\'rendered\'][\'#markup\'];
    print $pdf_url;
} else {
    global $base_url;
    $node_url = $base_url . \'/node/\' . $data->nid;
    print $node_url;
}
?>';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['use_php_click_sortable'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['php_click_sortable'] = '';
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'pdf' => 'pdf',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'pdf';
```

I'm sure you might be having some dummy content for that content-type, if not then do create couple of ones. Some with values in field_php and some with not!

and Voila! Here is your required output:

[image: preview]

## Updated Code:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'pdf';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'PDF';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'PDF';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: Content: PDF */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_pdf']['id'] = 'field_pdf';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_pdf']['table'] = 'field_data_field_pdf';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_pdf']['field'] = 'field_pdf';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_pdf']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_pdf']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_pdf']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_pdf']['alter']['path'] = '[field_pdf][path]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_pdf']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Global: PHP */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['id'] = 'php';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['field'] = 'php';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['alter']['path'] = '[php]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['alter']['absolute'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['use_php_setup'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['php_output'] = '<?php
if (isset($data->field_field_pdf[0][\'rendered\'][\'#markup\'])) {
    $pdf_url = $data->field_field_pdf[0][\'rendered\'][\'#markup\'];
    print $pdf_url;
} else {
    global $base_url;
    $node_url = $base_url . \'/node/\' . $data->nid;
    print $node_url;
}
?>';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['use_php_click_sortable'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['php_click_sortable'] = '';
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'pdf' => 'pdf',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'pdf';
```

Let me know if you need anything else from this.

Cheers!

Comment: I added content type PDF and field_pdf. Then I added content with pdf file and without pdf file. Imported new views with the views code above. But views shows only normal paths, not path to the file.

Comment: @hene, you mean to say you want clickable links?

Comment: Yes. Im building views which shows multiple content from multiple content types. And some of the content has link to the node itself but some content has PDF-file and in those link should be straight to PDF-file instead of node.

Comment: @hene, I've updated the post with the new code, please try re-importing it and do check it. I'm sure it will work as per your requirement. Let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: Ah, now it works. I imported updated views code AND changed Field Content: PHP Formatter from Generic file to URL to file.